# How to call a typescript class from a bash script

Tags: node.js, bash, typescript, shell

I want to call a typescript class and a function from a bash script file. I cannot find any documentation about that. Below is the code

Typescript code

```
export class TestClass {
    constructor(
    public name: string,
    public age: string,
  ) {
    const output = insertName(this.name, this.age)
  }

   public getNames() {
    return 'names'
   }
}
```

Bash script code

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
```

How can I call a typescript class and a function from a bash script

Answer (score 0):

Your code just defines and exports a class, it doesn't actually *do* anything with the class. For the bash script to call it and have it do something, you'll need code to (for instance) create an instance of the class and call a method, etc.

Once you have that, you have at least two options:

1. Compile the TypeScript to JavaScript and then use `node` to run it.
2. Use something like [`ts-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) that will compile it on demand and then run it.

Comment: Thank you. I can use ts-node to run it, but I only need to call it from bash. Is there any way to call this class from bash script, I need to know the syntax. Or I can simply create an instance and call a method in a bash script?

Comment: @JN_newbie - The two environments are completely separate. That's why I was saying that you need to have TypeScript code that actually does something. You can use bash to run a Node.js program (direclty, or indirectly via `ts-node`), and you can even pass input into that program and get output from it, but you can't directly interact with the class from bash. You need TypeScript/JavaScript code to do that.